# $\int_{0}^{6} \int_{0}^{y} x dx dy$ where $x = r \cos \theta, y = r \sin \theta, dx dy = r dr d \theta$

Tags: calculus, polar-coordinates

Given $x = r \cos \theta, y = r \sin \theta, dx dy = r dr d \theta$, how can I evaluate the following integral:
$\int_{0}^{6} \int_{0}^{y} x dx dy$

Comment: I would calculate it in Cartesian coordinates (do you need to evaluate it in polar coordinates?)

Answer (score 1):

First, substitute everything in for $x\,dx\,dy$.  Next find the limits of integration in terms of $r$ and $\theta$.  Personally, I recommend drawing a picture of the region of integration.